# Makefile and Boost URLS: Multiple definition of some function on compilation

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, linker-errors

Basically main.cpp depends on functions from server.cpp. So main includes server.hpp and server.cpp also needs to include server.hpp. Server.hpp includes boost::urls with the following include:

server.hpp

```
#ifndef _SERVER_H_
#define _SERVER_H_
...
#include <boost/url/src.hpp>
...
#endif
```

The problem is when I compile them separately as main.o and server.o and link them in the end for the program in the following makefile:

makefile

```
CC = g++
#C++ Version Number
VERSION = 2a
# compiler flags:
#  -g    - this flag adds debugging information to the executable file
#  -Wall  - this flag is used to turn on most compiler warnings
CXXFLAGS  = -std=c++$(VERSION) -g -Wall
LFLAGS    = -std=c++$(VERSION) -g -Wall -c
# Libraries
INC = $(shell pwd)/external_libraries/include/
LIB = $(shell pwd)/external_libraries/lib/
FLAGS = -lboost_coroutine -lboost_context -lboost_chrono -lcrypto -lssl -lboost_system -pthread -fcoroutines -lcassandra

main : main.o server.o cassandra/cql.o
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) main.o server.o cassandra/cql.o $(foreach inc,$(INC), -I$(inc)) $(foreach lib,$(LIB), -L$(lib)) $(FLAGS) -o main

main.o : ssl/server_certificate.hpp server.hpp main.cpp
    $(info Compiling Main.cpp)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) main.cpp $(foreach inc,$(INC), -I$(inc)) $(foreach lib,$(LIB), -L$(lib)) $(FLAGS) -o main.o


server.o : server_config.hpp server.hpp server.cpp
    $(info Compiling Server.cpp)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) server.cpp $(foreach inc,$(INC), -I$(inc)) $(foreach lib,$(LIB), -L$(lib)) $(FLAGS) -o server.o
```

I get a repeated errors like:

```
...
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/bin/ld: server.o: in function `boost::urls::parse(char const*&, char const*, boost::system::error_code&, boost::urls::userinfo_bnf&)':
/home/warrenniles/Desktop/project/webserver/external_libraries/include/boost/url/rfc/impl/userinfo_bnf.ipp:28: multiple definition of `boost::urls::parse(char const*&, char const*, boost::system::error_code&, boost::urls::userinfo_bnf&)'; main.o:/home/warrenniles/Desktop/project/webserver/external_libraries/include/boost/url/rfc/impl/userinfo_bnf.ipp:28: first defined here
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

or all in the form of:

```
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/bin/ld: server.o: in function `boost::urls::<function_def>:
/home/warrenniles/Desktop/project/webserver/external_libraries/include/boost/url/rfc/impl/userinfo_bnf.ipp:<some_number>: multiple definition of `boost::urls::<function_def>'; main.o:/home/warrenniles/Desktop/project/webserver/external_libraries/include/boost/url/rfc/impl/userinfo_bnf.ipp:<some_number>: first defined here
```

I would like to keep it such that I compile server.cpp, then compile main.cpp and then link them together in the end, but I am new to boost and make and do not know how to get around this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use it in header-only mode then `boost/url/src.hpp` must be included in exactly one translation unit. It is an alternative to linking it as a dynamic or static library. For declarations you should include other headers, such as `#include <boost/url/url.hpp>`